# Get Google Plus moments

Tags: android, google-plus

I'm trying to gets all the moments (check ins) of the user (not have to be the authenticated user).
Can it be done? 
On G+ documentation https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/moments/list it said:

> List all of the moments that your app has written for the authenticated user. Try it now or see an example.

Is it really only moments that my app insert and only for the authenticated user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it will only return the moments your app has written and only for the currently authenticated user.